# sending an image with mms on iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, image, share, mms

Searched the whole web for this with no solution...

I want to take a picture with the iphone camera and then be able to send it out via MMS/E-Mail.
This doesn't have to happen in my app, but at least I'd like to be able to call the MMS/E-Mail app and make it select the taken (and stored) picture.

When I use the built-in Photo-Album app, every picture has a button on the lower left corner which let's me share/print the actual photo...

So I kinda hope I'll be able to build something like that into my app...?

Any ideas?

[EDIT]

Thanks for the answers so far.

Meanwhile, I found out that I could at least send E-Mails and SMS's from within the «MessageUI»-Framework.
However, it seems that I can't add an image to the message-body of an SMS (damn)...

Comment: I did read that - but I don't really see what I'd have to work on?

Comment: You haven't marked any questions as accepted yet. i.e.: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fire an MMS/SMS programatically. You will need to hand over control to the UIImagePickerController and set its sourceType field to PhotoLibrary.

Cheers
Naren

Comment: Thanks Narren.
Actually, I do both - the user can either choose to take a pic with the cam or use an existing image from the library. But even with the sourceType set to PhotoLibrary, I don't get the «share»-Button... :(

Comment: Ah good point. I didn't realise that the share button doesn't show up.

Comment: you can try below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486638/in-the-ios-sdk-how-can-i-help-my-users-send-mms-intermixed-with-sms-from-my-app