# Send image in text message on ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sms

I'm trying to figure out how some apps send images attached to text messages. I don't see anything in MFMessageComposeViewController so ... any idea ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419742/sending-an-image-with-mms-on-iphone-programmatically

Comment: @Marvin - I believe the OP is talking about through the UI - not programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not currently possible;

[Is it possible to send a picture message using iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150271/is-it-possible-to-send-a-picture-message-using-iphone-sdk)

however there are alternatives;

[alternative for MFMessageComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919088/alternative-for-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller)