# In the iOS SDK, how can I help my users send MMS intermixed with SMS from my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, mms

An app that I am developing relies on the ability to help users send a mixture of images and text to their friends in one go.

I was hoping that MFMessageComposeViewController would offer some way to provide the user with an image in the body of the message, but evidently I can only suggest NSString for the body.

Alternatively, I could render the text into the image and then send that as well, but I still haven't found a way to suggest that the user send an image via MMS.

Is there a way to do either of these things?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same troubles with sending MMS.
I resolved it in this way:

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = yourImage;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:"]];
```

So firstly I copied needed image to clipboard and then open standard
`MFMessageComposeViewController` and paste this image from clipboard.
And of course You should have suitable settings for MMS on your phone.

Answer (score 3):

i think, you should use below code. because by default image type is jpeg for png images are not showing in iMessage when you try to paste.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aa1" ofType:@"png"]];
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

// or if image is jpeg then below code

```
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.jpeg"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:45263125"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot send MMS via iOS native SDK.

However we can iMessage a picture to a contact

This Method is tested and verified. I Used it in my code.

> if (![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
>
> ```
>     UIAlertView *alertV = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device not support SMS \nOr you
> ```
>
> hadn't login your iMessage" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
>   otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
>           [alertV show];
>           return;
>       }
>
> ```
> MFMessageComposeViewController *mVC = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
> mVC.body = @"jjjj";
> mVC.recipients = @[@"00XXXXXXXXXX"];
> mVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
> if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments]) {
>     NSLog(@"ok");
> }
> [mVC addAttachmentData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"], 1.0) typeIdentifier:@"public.data"
> ```
>
> filename:@"image.jpeg"];

```
[self presentViewController:mVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can use any jpeg jpg and png formats.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't send MMS using the iOS SDK.

You can however send both text and images via email using [`MFMailComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller).